# Populate variables in string retrieved from property

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Windows 10 UWP project but I believe this is a simple C#/.Net question. Typically, I would use string.Format to format a string with variables. Like this:

```
string.Format("My Name is: {0}", myName);
```

How would I do something similar is my string is stored as a propery?

```
public string Greeting { get; set; } = "My Name is: {0}";
```

When I retrieve this string be accessing the property, I get the same format that I would use in string.Format but I can't figure out how to still define {0} as myName?

Thanks!

Comment: I presume you've tried string.Format(Greeting, myName); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to set the property but return the fully formatted string, you would need to do this:

```
private string _greeting;

public string Greeting 
{
    get
    {
        return $"My Name is: {_greeting}";
    }
    set
    {
        _greeting = value;
    } 
}
```

However, I don't think that makes for particularly readable code. Instead, I would have a name property and a readonly greeting, something like this:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Greeting => $"My Name is: {Name}";
```

So now you can set and get the `Name` property while also generating a greeting.

Notice, I'm also using C# string interpolation here instead of `string.Format`. It looks a lot nice and is easier to read. It also requires C# version 6 or above (in other words, at least Visual Studio 2015.)

Answer (score 0):

A property is just an getter and setter wrapper for a variable.

Shouldn't you be calling

`Greeting = string.Format("My Name is: {0}", myName);` in your constructor or wherever you assign myName?

Answer (score 0):

if myName is a string property of your class, you don't need a setter for the greeting, and you can use:

`public string Greeting { get { return string.Format("My Name is: {0}", myName); } }`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
    string myName = "Steve";
    this.textBox1.Text = string.Format( "{0}{1}", Test.Greeting, myName );

    public class Test
    {
        public static string Greeting { get; set; } = "My Name is: ";
    }
```